# Tags are not fully visible when asking a question

Tags: bug, tags, design, user-interface

This only happens on this site and on the main Stack Overflow, not any other site (Tested on all SEs that start with A).
Before the `Post Your Question` button is the `Tags` bar where you put the Tags you would like for the question. The problem is, the tags go slightly to the left, and are cut off. Below are some pictures of this happening:

**Stack Overflow**

[Un-cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOCPo.png)

[image: Stack Overflow]

**Stack Overflow Meta**

[Un-cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FymHk.png)

[image: Stack Overflow Meta]

The pictures are of the whole box.
Click pictures to enlarge
I am on IE11 on Windows 8. This **only** happens when asking, not editing.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 42.0.2288.6.

Comment: Your pictures don't look off-center to me.

Comment: @Makoto Not off center per se just cropped off. Look at the **Tags** field. That's the whole box, and the first tag is partially outside.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  I still don't see it, but since I'm on a mobile I can't inspect the source.

Comment: @Makoto Cropped them to focus on the proper box

Comment: This is actually a known issue [that keeps coming back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197565/159034).

Comment: @KevinBrown For me it's happened *100%* of the time I've been on SO. (~2 months)